# How do I identify the correct type definitions to parameters of functions defined in @types/node?

Tags: typescript

In my `package.json` I have:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.5.1",
```

In my code I have:

```
            const hljs = require('highlight.js'); // https://highlightjs.org/

            highlight: function (str:any, lang:any) {
              if (lang && hljs.getLanguage(lang)) {
                try {
                  return '<pre class="hljs"><code>' +
                         hljs.highlight(lang, str, true).value +
                         '</code></pre>';
                } catch (__) {}
              }
```

Visual studio code automatically added the following package, thanks to the node dependency above I believe.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/highlight.js": "^9.12.3",
```

How do I identify the correct type definition to the parameters `str` and `lang` in the callback function above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@types` modules are third party type definitions for existing modules that you can see at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/

The ones for highlight.js specifically are https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/highlight.js/index.d.ts

Your editor may be able to get information about the exported type -- the `highlight` function in this case which will tell you what the arguments should be.

By looking at the type definitions on GitHub, the first two arguments to the `highlight` function are both `string`, so seems like you can do `str: string, lang: string`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code has some error, this makes no sense to me:

```
highlight: function // the ":" should be replaced to "=" ?
```

So what you are looking for might be this:

```
import * as hljs from 'highlight.js';
...
{
highlightFn: function (name: string, value: string): hljs.IHighlightResult {
    if (value && hljs.getLanguage(value)) {
      try {
          // return value of type "hljs.IHighlightResult" here (NOT a string)
      } catch (__) {}
    }
} as typeof hljs.highlight
}
...
```

Comment: Sorry, I cut two parts from my code. "highlight" is a property, thus the : and not the =